# NPM install fails, OSX

Tags: npm, node-gyp

I have been trying for ages to set up the dev environment for a new macbook. I could get my project from github just fine but whenever I run `npm install` to fetch the dependencies I encounter this `gyp` error. I have tried upgrading and downgrading `node`, clearing the cache. Deleting and re-setting up `node_modules`, but the error always remains the same. Any insight would be very much appreciated.

```
Shelleys-MBP:EvolveEducation-Mobile dommurphy$ npm install --legacy-peer-deps
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated read-package-tree@5.3.1: The functionality that this package provided is now in @npmcli/arborist
npm WARN deprecated ini@1.3.5: Please update to ini >=1.3.6 to avoid a prototype pollution issue
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated @google/maps@0.5.5: Please use @googlemaps/google-maps-services-js instead.
npm WARN deprecated phonegap-plugin-push@2.3.0: This package is deprecated, see https://blog.phonegap.com/update-for-customers-using-phonegap-and-phonegap-build-cc701c77502c
npm WARN deprecated @angular/http@7.2.16: Package no longer supported. Use @angular/common instead, see https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#angularhttp
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.4 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.4 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/dommurphy/Downloads/EvolveEducation-Mobile/node_modules/sharp
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install --runtime=napi) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)
npm ERR! info sharp Downloading https://github.com/lovell/sharp-libvips/releases/download/v8.9.1/libvips-8.9.1-darwin-x64.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.2 | darwin | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.7.3 found at "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/dommurphy/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/dommurphy/Downloads/EvolveEducation-Mobile/node_modules/sharp/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/dommurphy/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/dommurphy/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.13.2/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/dommurphy/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.13.2',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/dommurphy/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/dommurphy/Library/Caches/node-gyp/16.13.2/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/dommurphy/Downloads/EvolveEducation-Mobile/node_modules/sharp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info spawn make
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! You have not agreed to the Xcode license agreements, please run 'sudo xcodebuild -license' from within a Terminal window to review and agree to the Xcode license agreements.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 69
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/dommurphy/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.2.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/Users/dommurphy/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/bin/node" "/Users/dommurphy/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/dommurphy/Downloads/EvolveEducation-Mobile/node_modules/sharp
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/dommurphy/.npm/_logs/2022-02-17T09_10_41_869Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an error due to npm.

NPM install the package that has a build script to build node-gyp.
The build fails due to the license agreement with :

> You have not agreed to the Xcode license agreements, please run 'sudo
> xcodebuild -license' from within a Terminal window to review and agree
> to the Xcode license agreements.

so just run the command to accept the license agreement

```
sudo xcodebuild -license
```